# Pronoun or noun?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

In one of the Batman movies, the Joker greets someone as "Hello, beautiful".

Is "beautiful" a pronoun in this case? If it is not, what would you call it?

Thank you

Comment: It's an adjective used as a term of address.